# HttpError 400 Google API Error

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting the following error when fetching users and groups from Google. The funny thing is if I fetch users first they work and then groups don't. Or is I fetch groups first , I get them and then users don't.

I get the following error.

An error occurred: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&pageToken=AHmOf6YihZTS_nt0hqNMXlLn_iW1WewJbjn_mQWhEDMJstLNfcqg073_4cCIRv-GMgjVRa_aGlEfOqyBPLhe1mjH4qX18yK5gs8gNHY6q07jSF5Q4melg2CMgSjqzPHeVC3OMgdQykYUeuoITkfIzlZg8D6uZxO5rQ&alt=json returned "Invalid Input: pageToken">

Comment: Its saying returned "Invalid Input: pageToken" .. what else you need ?

Comment: Please follow these guidelines to ask your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve